# XenServer 8.0 running a NTP client in guest PVHVM VM

Tags: xen, xenserver, ntp, xcp-ng

I would like to run a NTP client in a Xen Linux VM under `XenServer` (`XCP-NG 8.0` to be precise).

The Linux VM, Debian Stretch 9.9 (`uname -a`: `Linux debian 4.9.0-9 amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u4 (2019-07-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux` has Xen guest tools 8.0 installed and is a `PVHVM` machine.

The VM is being synchronized to the host `/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource` prints `xen`

The usual tutorials I found online say to set the `xen.independent_wallclock=1` sysctl in VM's `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot the VM.

However these paths are unavaible to be set in sysctl.

`sysctl xen` returns only:
`xen.balloon.hotplug_unpopulated=0`

Perhaps this has changed in the newest versions.

What would be the equivalent of `xen.independent_wallclock` that needs to be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it changed almost a decade ago. independent_wallclock was [removed from pvops kernels](https://syslog.me/2011/01/05/independent-wallclock-in-xen-4/) for HVM/PVHVM domU guests. You don't need to do anything special now, just [run the NTP client as normal](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_FAQ_DomU#How_can_i_synchronize_a_dom0_clock.3F).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification